# A delete button is hiding behind another element. How can I make that element to be at the top so it's visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to draw a delete button right at the right top corner of the collapsible box. I already did it but for some reason I can't make it show at the top of the collapsible element so it's visible. I tried to set it to `visibility: visible` but I still can't make it visible. Any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div data-role='main' class='ui-content' id='collapse'>
    <div data-role='collapsible' data-theme='b' data-content-theme='b' data-iconpos='right' data-expanded-icon='collapse' data-collapsed-icon='expand'>
        <h4> 
            <a href='#' data-rel='back' data-role='button' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext' style='position:absolute;top:-20px;right: -10px'>Close</a> 

            <div class='ui-grid-a'> <div class='ui-block-a textfloatleft' > 1 new </div>

            <div class='ui-block-b textfloatright'>January 6th 2016</div>
        </div>

        <span id='collapstxt'> first </span> 

        <button href='#' id='bt01' data-icon='check' data-iconpos='right' style='width:100px;' onclick='alert(1);event.stopPropagation();' >Reply</button>
        </h4>

        <ul data-role='listview'>
            <li id='answerstyle'><span id='answerstxt'> first </span>
                <div class='ui-block-b answrfloatright'>January 6th 2016</div>
            </li>
            <li id='answerstyle'>Audi</li>
            <li id='answerstyle'>BMW</li>
            <li id='answerstyle'>Cadillac</li>
            <li id='answerstyle'>Ferrari</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my jsfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/yfu0yv9h/3/)

Comment: Are you asking how to move it into the box, or how to make it extend beyond the box?

Comment: And that's a crazy amount of markup inside a heading tag.

Comment: how to extend it beyond the box, I mean basically make it visible in the position it is right now.

Comment: Your markup has issues. I tried twice to format it, but you have at least one extra closing div tag in there. https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/yfu0yv9h/10/

Comment: @isherwood you are right about the crazy amount of markup but that's because I need it to make it like a balloon with a lot of information inside of it an content to display when you expand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the effect yore looking for you would need to add `overflow: visible;` to the containing element:

`a.ui-collapsible-heading-toggle.ui-btn.ui-icon-expand.ui-btn-icon-right.ui-btn-b { overflow:visible;}`

Here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yfu0yv9h/12/)

Comment: Very nice, until you actually click it. :P

Comment: Interesting, but how did you get that css element? I can't find it.

Comment: I just noticed it, that's the css for the collapsible heading, it's weird that that rule applies for that button.